# Popen prepending path to executable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using popen to run the following command on a windows vm

> 'tf changeset ...'

however when I run it using

```
commandLine = 'tf changeset /noprompt /latest /loginType:OAuth /login:.,***'

process = Popen(commandLine, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I see the following being executed in the logs

> 'C:\Azure\Agent-1/externals/tf/tf changeset ...'

Meaning that 'C:\Azure\Agent-1/externals/tf/' has been prepended to my command. I was just expecting to see

> 'tf changeset ...'

Unfortunately adding the path to the execution breaks the command, is there any way to stop python from doing this?

Comment: How do you add the path ?

Comment: Sorry Maurice not sure what you mean, I am not adding the path.  I expected to see in the logs the following being executed:  'tf changeset ...' but instead see 'C:\Azure\Agent-1/externals/tf/tf changeset ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `commandLine` to `Popen` as a list of arguments:

```
commandLine = ["tf", "changeset", "/noprompt", "/latest", "/loginType:OAuth", "/login:.,***'"]
process = Popen(commandLine, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: I thought when using Popen on windows with shell=True you should pass everything as a string?

Comment: As per the documentation, you should beasically never need `shell=True` on Windows (either).

Answer (score 1):

Python by itself does no such thing. Perhaps the `shell=True` is doing more than you hoped or bargained for? But we would need access to your shell's configuration to get beyond mere speculation around this.

Calling `Popen` on the result from `Popen` is obviously not well-defined; but perhaps this is just an error in your transcription of your real code?

Removing the first `process =Popen(` would fix this with minimal changes. As per the above, I would also remove `shell=True` as at least superfluous and at worst directly harmful.

```py
commandLine = 'tf changeset /noprompt /latest /loginType:OAuth /login:.,***'
process = Popen(commandLine, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Like the `subprocess` documentation tells you, `shell=True` is only useful on Windows when your command is a `cmd` built-in.

For proper portability, you should break the command into tokens, manually or by way of `shlex.split()` if you are lazy or need the user to pass in a string to execute.

```py
commandLine = ['tf ', 'changeset', '/noprompt', '/latest', '/loginType:OAuth', '/login:.,***']
process = Popen(commandLine, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

This avoids [the other dangers of `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and will be portable to non-Windows platforms (assuming of course that the command you are trying to run is available on the target platform).

Comment: Apologies triplee the additional process=Popen was a copy paste mistake.  I've amended the question.  I will look into shell=True, appreciate the answer.